# How to get an RTK Query API endpoint state (isLoading, error, etc) in a React Class component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Ok, I think I've gone through almost all of RTK Query's docs, and read up on RTK Query's caching. Seems like it's a pretty big part of it, even if its not something I need at the moment.

So, I'm trying to do a simple query using RKT Query in a class-based component, and then select from the Redux Store the isLoading state for the endpoint call. However, currently in the `render() {}` of my `LoginPage.jsx`, the `endpoint.<name>.select()(state)`  call on `mapStateToProps`  within `LoginPageContainer.jsx` doesn't seem to be working. (See code below).

From looking at the examples from the docs on [using RTK Query on classes](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/usage-without-react-hooks#examples), it looks like I'm missing a "cache key" in the `.select(<cache_key>)(state)` call. However, I haven't incorporated tags in my endpoint yet (I believe I don't have a need for them yet).

**My question:**

Can someone shed some light on what's the proper use on RTK Query generated endpoint's `select()` method used outside of React Hooks? I understand the idea behind cache tags for automatic re-fetching (but that's not likely what's wrong here), but I'm not sure how or what cache key I'm missing here to just get the running endpoint query state in a class component. Thanks, everyone!

**The Code:**

```js
// LoginPage.jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PT from 'prop-types'
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm'

export default class LoginPage extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    loginWithUsername: PT.func.isRequired,
    loginWithUsernameState: PT.object.isRequired
  }

  render() {
    // This value never updates
    const { isLoading } = this.props.loginWithUsernameState
    // always outputs "{"status":"uninitialized","isUninitialized":true,"isLoading":false,"isSuccess":false,"isError":false}"
    // Even during and after running the `loginWithUsername` endpoint query
    console.log(this.props.loginWithUsernameState)
    return (
      <div>
        {isLoading && 'Loading ...'}
        <LoginForm
          onSubmit={(values) => this.props.loginWithUsername(values)} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

// LoginPageContainer.jsx
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { teacherApi } from './api'
import LoginPage from './LoginPage'

const { loginWithUsername } = teacherApi.endpoints

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  loginWithUsernameState: loginWithUsername.select()(state)
})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  loginWithUsername: (payload) => dispatch(loginWithUsername.initiate(payload))
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginPage)

// api.js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'

export const teacherApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'teacherApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: '/teacher/' }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    loginWithUsername: builder.query({
      query: (data) => ({
        url: 'login',
        method: 'post',
        body: data,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
      }),
    }),
  }),
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "cache key" passed to `endpoint.select()` is the same variable you're passing to your hook:

```js
useGetSomeItemQuery("a");
useGetSomeItemQuery("b");

const selectSomeItemA = endpoint.select("a");
const selectSomeItemB = endpoint.select("b");

const itemAREsults = selectSomeItemA(state);
const itemBResults = selectSomeItemB(state);
```

This results in looking up `state => state[apiSlice.reducerPath].queries["getSomeItem('a')"]`, or whatever the exact cached data field is for that item.

Comment: Okay, the data return the status of `uninitialized`. How do I fix this?

Comment: @AdewaleOlaoye It would be better to ask this as a separate question so you can provide details on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @markerikson, where is 'state' coming from in endpoint.select("a")(state)?

Comment: @nadiTime : anywhere you have access to the entire Redux root state: a `useSelector` hook, `mapStateToProps` in `connect`, a thunk with `getState()`, a saga with `yield select(selector)`, etc.  See https://redux.js.org/usage/deriving-data-selectors .

Answer (score 0):

```
const result = api.endpoints.getPosts.select()(state)
const { data, status, error } = result
```

> Note that unlike the auto-generated query hooks, derived booleans such
> as isLoading, isFetching, isSuccess are not available here. The raw
> status enum is provided instead.

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/usage-without-react-hooks